# Django image field default image

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

**How to set the default image in my profile_picture?**

```
profile_image = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True, upload_to="images/", default='post_user/image/profile_image.png')
```

Comment: Just put the name of the image.

Comment: Whats is the issue you are facing. Explain in brief